# How can i set retry listener for a kafka batch consumer when using spring-kafka-2.2.7.RELEASE?

Tags: spring-kafka

I'm using spring-kafka '2.2.7.RELEASE' to create a batch consumer and I'm trying to set up a custom retry listener for some internal logging purpose. How can i configure this?

Comment: 2.2.x is no longer supported; but you can add a listener to the `RetryTemplate` as usual.

Comment: Thanks @GaryRussell for the clarification.